# Process list with name and VPRVT

Tags: applescript, macos

Is there any way to get just name and VPRVT of running processes?

Comment: Something like `ps -o pid,vsz` or are you looking for help running AppleScript to call unix commands?

Comment: Yes something like that. I tried your code, but all i got was 2 numbers. My AppleScript needs name and VPRVT of every running process. Thanks

Comment: @bmike vsz (vsize / total virtual memory available) is not vprvt (used virtual private memory). top without arguments has columns for both.

Comment: @LauriRanta you are totally correct. My fishing lessons were quite vague here - more there are several manuals than RTFM.

Answer (score 2):

```
top -stats command,vprvt -l1 | sed '1,/^COMMAND *VPRVT/d'
```

`-stats` = shown columns, `-l1` = exit after one sample. It cuts off long command names and uses human-readable sizes though.

Comment: do shell script "top -stats command,vprvt -l1 -o vprvt | sed '1,/^COMMAND *VPRVT/d'" Thanks Lauri, your code is what i was looking for. I figured out how to sort by vprvt. It could show longer process names too and for some reason, it shows all my running AppleScripts as "applet".

Answer (score 0):

You could always restrict the columns Activity Monitor shows by right clicking the a column and deselect everything except Virtual Private Memory

[image: screenshot of Activity Monitor]